# Strange behaviour in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

```
template <typename T> T& larger(T& a, T& b)
{
    return (a>b?a:b);
}


 std::string first {"vv"};
 std::string second {"That is the question in californian"};


 int main(){
 std::cout << larger(first,second) << std::endl;
 }
```

This should return [if a greater than b , then a , else b ]; but it returns a for me .("vv")
What went wrong here >

Comment: "*This should return [if a greater than b , then a , else b ];*" Why should it return that? You called a function. That function has a return value. That return value is *not* its source code converted to readable text.

Comment: Shouldn't it return b in this case , the second string . Help, starting out templates . Thanks!

Comment: No, because `<` and `>` for `std::string` are lexicoraphical order, not length comparison.

Comment: This code is working correctly.

Comment: "vv" is greater than "That is the question in californian"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator<` compares lexicographically for `std::string`. This means that it compares character by character, starting from the first, and only if they are equal, it compares the next one.

As you can easily verify, it holds that `'v' > 'T'`. That is because lowercase letters come *after* uppercase letters in ASCII encoding.

Comment: std::string first {"aaaaa"};
std::string second {"ttttt"}; prints b as the code intended to .

Answer (score 0):

The operator > and < compares both the strings not based upon the length but based on lexicographic order i.e. ASCII values.